# Python: How to get a variable's value updated every call?

Tags: python, variables, time, epoch

Newbie question: How can I print a variable's current value at the moment when it is called, instead of getting its old value when it was first defined?

```
epoch = int(time.time()*1000)
print epoch
time.sleep(2)
print epoch # it should now be 2 seconds larger, but isn't.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd have to make a function for that. Something like this should suffice?

```
epoch = lambda: int(time.time()*1000)
print epoch()
time.sleep(2)
print epoch()
```

You could also encase this into a class and make a `@property` out of it, so that you can get a value without using brackets `()`

Comment: That was... so simple.

Answer (score 2):

You must to be confusing *assignment* of a variable with *definition* of a function.  In your example, `epoch` is assigned only once, and will keep that value until you set it to something else.  It won't change its value just because it was initially set as a result of a function call.

If you want a value that changes or updates, you'll have to make a *function call* either as @Rusty has described, or `def` a function.